# Can't add Google account after phone reset

Tags: google-account, connection-issues

I have a Leagoo Lead 3 running Android 4.4 KitKat. After factory resetting it, I'm no able to add my Google account.

The error I receive is

> Couldn't sign in
> There was a problem communicating with Google servers. Try again later.

Googling it, I find that the `hosts` file in `/system/etc` needed to be modified to comment out `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx android.clients.Google.com`, but I don't have this line.

Also, I checked HTTP traffic with Fiddler and I just have this :

> "200 HTTP Tunnel to 173.194.40.142:443" with body 0

It seems to be a good Google IP.

I don't know what to check now. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/zGCCBpsvusw) post on Google Forums:

1. Check if two-step  verification been enabled on the account (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en&ref_topic=2784804)?
2. Try to open a browser on the device, go to https://mail.google.com/ and sign into your account.
3. Also try the Unlock Captcha function (http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=78754):  https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
   You can try disabling IMAP (from the web-interface) and re-enabled it.  Or deleting the account from the device and setting it up again.

> NOTE:  When two-step verification is enabled for an account, you need
>   to create an application specific password (to be used in place of
>   your regular password) for any client/application/device that doesn't
>   know how to ask for the 2-step code (like your phone).
>
> Check
>   https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1173270
>
> From: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/zGCCBpsvusw

Other possible solutions:

- [[XDA Developers][Solved] can't acces/sign in google account after factory reset](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2178799)
- [[AndroidForums][SOLUTION]Cannot add Google account after factory reset](http://androidforums.com/threads/solution-cannot-add-google-account-after-factory-reset.695054/)

The first one works if you can't estabilish connection to Google servers, the second one needs rooting the phone (Remember: you do it only on your own risk)

Hope it help

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I finally flashed a rom to retrieve connection.
The first solution shouldn't have worked because I had no connection at all, like I saw it with fiddler and using anything as email and password did the same.
The second solution is what I tried like I said.

Answer (score 0):

From [QYOBZ's post on XDA Forums - [SOLUTION:] Can't Establish a reliable connection to the server/Playstore No Connect](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/solution-cant-establish-a-reliable-connection-to-the-server-playstore-no-connect.2110225/post-36985441)

> 1. **ROOT** your device (of course)
> 2. Editing the file
>    You will need a proper editor
>    Download and Install Total Commander and open it
>    OR DOWNLOAD BELOW
> 3. Browse with Total Commander to root/etc
>    (hint: on the right side of the screen there's a shortcut to system  folder.. look for etc/ and you will find it)
>    Tap mount R/W
>    Long tap on "hosts" > edit file > Totalcmd-Editor
>
>    Open etc/hosts and edit the file. Just put # before 74.125.93.113 android.clients.google.com.
> 4. SAVED
>
>    Edited file should look like this:
>
>    ```
>    127.0.0.1 localhost
>    #74.125.93.113 android.clients.google.com
>    ```
>
>    remember: based on my own observation it should be look like this:
>
>    ```
>    127.0.0.1(just one space)localhost
>    #74.125.93.113(just one space)android.clients.google.com
>    ```
> 5. Turn OFF your device.
> 6. (Not Necessary, Go to Next Step. But if the problem persist do Factory Reset..) Got it on Recovery Mode, Factory Data Reset, wipe data.
> 7. Reboot your device.
> 8. Once the phone reboots, input your google account information when the phone asks for it.
> 9. Sync to your account and contacts